# Countable Union on uncountable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Have I understood this correctly?

If a set is uncountable then it's impossible to do a countable union of all the elements, because infinitely many would be left out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were able to form a union using countable sets then this would imply the union is also countable .

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "union of all the elements". One takes unions of sets, not elements. If by this you mean $\bigcup \{x_i\}$ for some sequence $\{x_i\}$ of elements of the set, then no. As Quality said, that union is countable. But if you mean $\bigcup A_i$ for some countable collection of subsets $A_i$ of your set, then yes, the union of that collection can be uncountable, provided that at least one of the sets $A_i$ is uncountable.

Comment: Thank you Paul that was exactly what I needed